# Set type to next and error in observable before subscribing

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have the following code:

```js
public request<T = any>(
  method: string,
  route: string,
  body?: Record<string, any>
): Observable<HttpResponse<T> | HttpError> {
  return this.http
    .request<HttpResponse<T>>(method, `${this.apiUrl}\/${route}`, {
      responseType: 'json',
      body,
    })
    .pipe(
      catchError((response: HttpErrorResponse) => this.handleError(response))
    );
}
```

However setting the return type of the method to `Observable<HttpResponse<T> | HttpError>` is not working because typescript thinks that when subscribing to the observable the function `next:` can return both `HttpResponse<T>` and `HttpError` while what I wanted to do was set the `next:` type to `HttpResponse<T>` and the `error:` type to `HttpError`.

Is this possible?

Comment: Type inference comes in very handy here.